# Can't assign keys programmatically to bookmarks in a loop

Tags: emacs, elisp

Suppose, we have n bookmarks in the list (n <= 9)

```
% Bookmark
- --------
1  mark-1                     ~/work/file-1.txt
2  mark-2                     ~/work/file-2.txt
  ...
9  mark-9                     ~/work/file-9.txt
```

I wanted to programmatically attach key `<n>` to jump to n-th bookmark.

### Code

```
;get a sorted list of bookmarks
(let ((bookmarks (sort (bookmark-all-names) 'string<))
      (i 1))
  (while bookmarks
    (setq key (number-to-string i))
    ;try to assign key i -> jump-to-bookmark(bookmarks[i])
    (define-key bookmark-bmenu-mode-map
      (kbd key)
      (lambda () (interactive) (bookmark-jump (car bookmarks))))
    ;next bookmark
    (setq bookmarks (cdr bookmarks))
    (setq i (+ i 1))
              ))
```

Unfortunately, it gives an error:

> (wrong-type-argument integer-or-marker-p key)

Comment: Is `defkey-arg` a macro of yours?  Hopefully, if you share it or share the name of the package that exports it, it will be easier to spot the issue.

Comment: @juanleon Sorry, we don't need this macro here. I replaced it with standard function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue here is related to the fact that you are using dynamic binding, but trying to access from a lambda a variable that is not in scope anymore (bookmarks).  You can fix it by defining the lambda this way:

```
`(lambda () (interactive) (bookmark-jump (car ',bookmarks))))
```

You can see an explanation [here](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/10394/scope-in-lambda).

(btw, code will fail when you have more than 9 bookmarks)

This is the modified code that works fine for me:

```
(let ((bookmarks (sort (bookmark-all-names) 'string<))
      (i 1)
      key)
  (while bookmarks
    (setq key (number-to-string i))
    (define-key bookmark-bmenu-mode-map
      (kbd key)
      `(lambda () (interactive) (bookmark-jump (car ',bookmarks))))
    (setq bookmarks (cdr bookmarks))
    (setq i (+ i 1))))
```

Comment: So, it must be a macro. But it still gives an error: (wrong-type-argument integer-or-marker-p key). Maybe, something is wrong here: `(kbd key)`

Comment: In the help for keys function it says "KEYS should be a string constant", I have a variable. But how to use a variable?

Comment: Your code, with my change, works fine for me (emacs 24.4, less than 10 bookmarks).  I added `key` to the `let`, by the way, to avoid polluting the namespace.

Comment: "Your code, with my change, works fine for me (emacs 24.4)" - erm, doesn't work here (emacs 24.2) - I also used let*. Can you post your code?

Comment: @user4035 done.  When I eval the code above the key bindings are created flawlessly.